# Quero Pegar o Resultado de um Select para usar no JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Estou querendo pegar a opção escolhida pela pessoa e simplesmente printar na tela(é apenas o básico, para depois fazer oq eu realmente quero), So que não sei fazer isso. A Parte do codigo do HTML que tem {{ valor }} é onde eu quero que apareça o q foi selecionado na caixa de escolha.Obs, preciso dessa informação para poder usar no código de JavaScript e não no HTML, par mais tarde poder para cada tipo de escolha fazer algo diferente no JS...Meu código a seguir:

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="java.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="pag" ng-controller = "botao">

    <div ng-repeat = "fig in figuras">
        <select>
            <option ng-model = "escolha" Ng-repeat = "x in name">{{x}}</option>
        </select>
        <caixa ng-repeat = "ponto in fig.pontos">
            <input type = "text" ng-model="ponto.x" size = "5">
        </caixa>    
    </div>
    <div>
        <button  ng-click="mais()" >Adicionar mais</button>

    </div>
    valor: {{ valor }}


</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript:

```
class Ponto {
contructor(x,y){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
   }
}

class Figura {
    constructor(){
        this.pontos = [];
        this.pontos.push(new Ponto());
        this.pontos.push(new Ponto());
    }   
}

var pag = angular.module('pag', [])
pag.controller('botao',function($scope){
    $scope.name = ["Linha","circulo"]
    $scope.figuras=[]
    $scope.mais = function(){
        f1 = new Figura();
        $scope.figuras.push(f1);
    }
    $scope.pontos       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

A forma mais simples é usar o *two way data binding*, que seria a comunicação de duas vias, ou seja, o HTML altera a variável no JavaScript, e alterações na variável JavaScript também altera o HTML

No HTML precisa iniciar a aplicação (`ng-app`), o controlador (`ng-controller`) e adicionar o atributo `ng-model` na tag `select` (não na `option`). Atenção, é necessário prefixar as variáveis, tanto no `ng-model` e na interpolação HTML (`{{ }}`) com o nome do controle, que pode ser apelidado com o `as` na sua declaração

```
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
    <!-- Importa os scripts necessários -->
</head>
<body ng-controller="exemplo as ex">
    <select ng-model="ex.escolha">
        <option value="op1">Op 1</option>
        <option value="op2">Op 2</option>
        <option value="op3">Op 3</option>
    </select>
    <p>{{ex.escolha}}</p>
</body>
```

No Javascript basta iniciar a aplicação, criar um controlador passando uma função construtora e definir a variável

```
angular
    .module('app', [])
    .controller('exemplo', function() {
        this.escolha = "op2"; //Valor padrão
    });
```

Essa é apenas um exemplo simples

Comment: mas isso não pegaria apenas a op1 1?Como eu pegaria o resultado que a pessoa escolheu? faria this.escolha = "ex.escolha" ?

Comment: O resultado estaria na variável `escolha` do controlador `exemplo`, que, no hTML pode ser acessado por `exemplo.escolha` ou, usando um alias `ex.escolha`, editei a pergunta, veja se ficou mais claro

Answer (score 0):

Pelo que entendi tu tens uma lista de figuras e quer adicionar valores a esta lista à partir das opções de um selectbox.

Neste caso, o melhor seria usar "ng-options" dentro da tag "select". Desse modo, o "ng-model" mudaria de valor sempre que o usuário escolhesse uma opção, conforme código abaixo:

HTML:

```
<html ng-app="myApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.6/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myController">
    <select ng-model="escolha" ng-options="item for item in opcoes">
        <option value="">Escolha uma opção</option>
    </select>

    <button ng-click="maisFiguras()">Adicionar</button>
    <p>{{ Opção do usuário: " + escolha }}</p>
    <p>{{ "Figuras: " + opcoes}}</p>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
        app.controller("myController", function($scope){
            $scope.opcoes = ["Linha","Circulo","Quadrado"];

            $scope.maisFiguras = function(){
                $scope.opcoes.push($scope.escolha);
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```